# Delimiters in Mtpro2

Tags: delimiters, mtpro

Some delimiters do not appear as they should when using `mtpro2` package

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\let\myBbbk\Bbbk
\let\Bbbk\relax
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}

\begin{document}
\[\lmoustache\rmoustache\lgroup\rgroup\]
\end{document}
```

Here is what I get
[image]

Here is what it should look like (I suppose).
[image]

Comment: The `mtpro2` package uses different encodings for the math fonts and doesn't define those commands, so the legacy definition is used, which points to slots that don't contain the pieces that build them in the standard setup.